# PHP pack function

Tags: php

Why `pack()` gives the same result for signed and unsigned format codes?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php

> Note that the distinction between signed and unsigned values only
>   affects the function unpack(), where as function pack() gives the same
>   result for signed and unsigned format codes.

Comment: Because it is implemented this way?

Comment: @AlexBlex why? I want to pack signed integer to send it to an API, is it important? maybe the API server unpack it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The packed integer is a 32/64 bit dword/qword, which holds no information whether it is signed integer or not. Interpretation of the highest bit comes on unpacking stage only.

I strongly recommend to check documentation for the *API server* regarding data format. Apart from interpretation of the sing bit, it should mention length of integers and [byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Also, please read

> **Caution** Note that PHP internally stores integer values as signed values of a machine-dependent size (C type long)....

part of the page you referred to.

Working with binary data it is your responsibility to ensure correct packing. I.e. if *API server* expects signed 32int, you should ensure the integer you send is no more than 2,147,483,647 (0x7FFF FFFF), otherwise it will be interpreted as a negative number; and vice versa if *API server* expects unsigned int32, it doesn't matter how hard you *want* to pack a signed integer - the result will be unpacked as a positive number.